# How to distinguish X25519 output from random?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, distinguisher, x25519

Suppose that Alice has an X25519 key pair $\{S_A,P_A\}$ (secret and public key, respectively). Using *randomly selected* X25519 public keys $\{P_*\}$ (such that $P_A\notin \{P_*\}$), Alice calculates several values $X_* = \operatorname{X25519}(S_*,P_*)$.

She then repeatedly flips a (fair) coin. Each time, if the result is heads, she sends a (truly) random 256-bit string to Bob. If the result is tails, she sends some value in $\{X_*\}$ to Bob. Bob does not know the result of the coin flip.

I know that the output of the ECDH function is not uniformly random, so ***how* can Bob determine—with more than 50% accuracy—whether Alice has sent him a random string or a value from the set $\{X_*\}$?**

Bob knows $P_A$ and the curve parameters, but he does not know the elements of the set $\{X_*\}$.

---

This question is distinct from [Distinguishing x25519 public keys from random?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61777), which asks about distinguishing X25519 *public **keys*** from random. This question asks about distinguishing the ***output** of the X25519 function* (i.e., the *shared secret computed with the ECDH function*) from random. Given two secret, public key pairs $\{S_A,P_A\}$ and $\{S_B,P_B\}$, that is, this question asks how to distinguish $\operatorname{X25519}(S_A,P_B)$ (or, equivalently, $\operatorname{X25519}(S_B,P_A)$) from random, while the other question asks how to distinguish $P_A$ and $P_B$ from random.

---

**Edit:** Fixed names of variables. $S_*$ was intended to be $X_*$.

Comment: Note that I don't see how this question is distinct from the last link.

Comment: +1 agree it is either , very identical, or a small change, - @BenZ how is the question *distinct* ?

Comment: @WilliamMartens The other question asks about distinguishing X25519 *public **keys*** from random. This question asks about distinguishing the ***output** of the X25519 function* (i.e., the *shared secret computed with the ECDH function*) from random. Given two secret, public key pairs $\{S_A,P_A\}$ and $\{S_B,P_B\}$, that is, this question asks how to distinguish $\operatorname{X25519}(S_A,P_B)$ (or, equivalently, $\operatorname{X25519}(S_B,P_A)$) from random, while the other question asks how to distinguish $P_A$ and $P_B$ from random.

Comment: @BenZ. Ohh okay, put that in the question :) so we know exactly that what it means

Comment: Done—thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @BenZ. Thanks a lot! and no worries!  Wishes from Sweden ^_^

Answer (score 3):

> Alice generates several $X_* = \operatorname{X25519}(S_*,P_*)$.

If Alice uses the X25519 function, the output will belong to $\mathbb{F_{2^{255}-19}}$ and will represent a $X$-coordinate of a point in the large prime-order subgroup of curve25519.
This information can be used by Alice to distinguish from random 256 bit strings.

1. Bob can look at the most significant bit $MSB(X_*)$, that due to little endian representation of X25519 this will be the eight bit from the right. This is zero for all public keys generated with $\operatorname{X25519}$ function. So if $MSB(X_*) = 1$ then Bob knows this is the random string.
2. Given $X_*$ with $MSB(X_*)=0$ Bob can compute the square root of the value $X_*^3 + 486662X_*^2 + X_*$ in $\mathbb{F_{2^{255}-19}}$. If $X_*$ doesn't have a square root in the field then Bob knows this is the random string. On average, about half the value won't have a valid square root.

This two combined information allows Bob to distinguish with certainty that about $\frac{3}{4}$ of the random string are indeed random strings. This can be used to have an overall guessing accuracy of 75%.

Please note that the proper way of doing what the user is asking, without giving any advantage to Bob, would be to use the [elligator](https://www.shiftleft.org/papers/elligator/elligator.pdf) scheme to encode public key points, but then there is a restriction on the usable public keys.

Answer (score -1):

The 248'th bit (big-endian) in the scalar multiplication is always set to zero.

Comment: What about the lower bits?

Comment: I see no reasons why the 248'th bit (big-endian) of the _result_ of a scalar multiplication would be 0, in whatever common coordinate system. And I see no other well-defined meaning to the statement made.

Comment: See 1st point in Ruggero's answer. An eighth bit from the right is 248th bit from the left.