# Distinguishing EC Public Key from random

Tags: elliptic-curves, x25519

I recently read the post [Distinguishing x25519 public keys from random?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61777/distinguishing-x25519-public-keys-from-random) and found myself wondering why, for a randomly chosen
x, the result of the function $$x^3+ax^2+x$$ is a square in 50% of cases and not in the other 50%. I understand that in a finite field with an odd prime order, a randomly chosen x is a square in 50% of cases, but I don't see how this directly translates to the above claim.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argument towards $x^3+ax^2+x$ being a square modulo $q$ for *around* 50% of $x$ when $a,q$ are the parameters in [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519): we know $y^2\equiv x^3+ax^2+x\pmod q$ defines a proper elliptic curve group. By [Hasse's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) it's order (number of elements) $N$ is<sup>*</sup> such that
$$\bigl|N-\left(q+1\right)\bigr|\,\le\,2\sqrt q\tag{1}\label{fgr1}$$
The elements can be classified as:

- the unity of the group (aka point at infinity).
- $(x,y)=(0,0)$, in which case $x^3+ax^2+x\equiv0\pmod q$ thus $x^3+ax^2+x$ is a square modulo $q$
- other points $(x,y)\in[0,p]$ with $y^2=x^3+ax^2+x\equiv0\pmod q$.

Therefore there are $N-2$ points of the later kind. They go in pairs sharing the same $x\bmod q\ne0$, because if point $(x,y)$ satisfies the curve's equation and $x\bmod q\ne0$, then $(x,q-y)$ is a *different* point that also satisfies the curve's equation.

Therefore there are $1+(N-2)/2=N/2$ values of $x\in[0,q)$ with $x^3+ax^2+x\bmod q$ a square. That's a proportion $r=N/(2q)$.

Dividing $(\ref{fgr1})$ by $2q$, we get
$$\Biggl|\,\frac N{2q}-\left(\frac12+\frac1{2q}\right)\Biggr|\,\le\,\frac1{\sqrt q}\tag{2}\label{fgr2}$$
thus
$$\Biggl|\,r-\frac12\Biggr|\,\le\,\frac1{\sqrt q}+\frac1{2q}\tag{3}\label{fgr3}$$
And since $q$ is 255-bit, $r\approx1/2$ for all practical purposes.

---

<sup>*</sup> More precisely, for Curve25519, $p=2^{255}-19$ and $N=8\ell$ with $\ell=2^{252}+ 27742317777372353535851937790883648493$